# How do I add data (that's not in a table) to my collection?

Tags: magento-1.7, collection

Specifically, in my adminhtml Grid.php I created a $collection in _prepareCollection() by using the getSelect()->join() and it works great. I've merged several tables.

Now I want to create a custom column that includes a value based on sku. Lets call it product type. I would like to do something like this:

```
    foreach($collection as $item):
        if($item->getSku() == 'fresh')     
            $item->setData('product_material','Fresh');
        else
            $item->setData('product_material','Not Fresh');
        $item->save();
    endforeach;
```

I have more complex logic to build the product material, but you should get the point. The fact I found no clue on how to do this also tells me I'm probably approaching this incorrectly. Is there a better way to do this or a place to handle this?

I don't want to store this in a table yet because we are still defining what inputs generate the material type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create this computed column on-the-fly (saving objects don't make sense). Check out this post ([link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192232/#t239222)). It shows you how to add a calculated column and how to fully functionalize it.

Comment: Thank you, that forum post was great. One note, the specific case required his index => 'created_at' which is rather unique. If it's text like mine, just use the variable name